# ETL with Kafka and MongoDB as A Source

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, apache-kafka, aws-lambda, etl

I am just learning about Apache Kafka. My current ETL is running on batch process and now I want it to run on stream process so that the data used for reporting is always up to date. 
As far as I understand I can use MongoDB connector to capture data change from mongodb then send it to a kafka topic. But in my ETL I need to store the data after being processed to an SQL database. 
How and where can I process the data sent from mongodb to a topic then create a record from it to another database? Can I use an AWS lambda function to do the processing and record creation? But then, how can I call this function from kafka?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer to your question is [Kafka Connect](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/index.html?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=rmoff&utm_campaign=ty.community.con.rmoff_stackoverflow_2020-06-17&utm_term=rmoff-devx). The longer answer is Kafka Connect plus stream processing (such as Kafka Streams, ksqlDB, etc).

Your pipeline would look something like:

- Read from MongoDB with Kafka Connect (e.g. [this connector](https://www.confluent.io/hub/debezium/debezium-connector-mongodb) or [this connector](https://www.confluent.io/hub/mongodb/kafka-connect-mongodb)). Here's an [example](https://rmoff.net/2018/03/27/streaming-data-from-mongodb-into-kafka-with-kafka-connect-and-debezium/)
- Optionally, process the data (filter, enrich, aggregate, join) with stream processing. Here's an [example](https://www.confluent.io/blog/data-wrangling-apache-kafka-ksql/?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=rmoff&utm_campaign=ty.community.con.rmoff_stackoverflow_2020-06-17&utm_term=rmoff-devx) using ksqlDB.
- Sink the data to database using Kafka Connect and the [JDBC Sink connector](https://www.confluent.io/hub/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc). Here's an [example tutorial](https://rmoff.dev/kafka-jdbc-video).

Here's a more general overview of using Kafka in ETL as both a [blog](https://www.confluent.io/blog/changing-face-etl/?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=rmoff&utm_campaign=ty.community.con.rmoff_stackoverflow_2020-06-17&utm_term=rmoff-devx) and a [talk](https://rmoff.dev/oredev19-changing-face-of-etl). You can learn more about Kafka Connect in [this talk](http://rmoff.dev/ksldn19-kafka-connect).